# Unable to install phpmyadmin

Tags: raspbian, phpmyadmin

I have installed `nginx` on Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch and installed `Wordpress`
In the process I ran the following

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

I setup MariaDB and set up WordPress Database with

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysql -uroot -p
create database wordpress;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'redacted';
```

I have done some WordPress configuration, and wanted to backup my WordPress

I attempted to install `phpmyadmin` (`sudo apt install phpmyadmin`), but this keeps failing with error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
There seems to be no option to enter the password for root@localhost

I have tried to interrogate `MariaDB` which shows:-

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2

Connection id:      104
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         18 hours 43 min 19 sec

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| wordpress          |
+--------------------+
```

So no `phpmyadmin` database seems to have been created.

**Can anyone help me install `phpmyadmin` ?**

Would manually creating database phpmyadmin help?

---

EDIT

Based on the answer by @Kramer this seemed to be a known problem with Debian (I thought Debian packages were meant to be checked).

I have now performed the following steps (file locations differed from suggested)

```
cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql/
create database phpmyadmin;

mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql

    create database phpmyadmin;
    grant all privileges on phpmyadmin.* to phpmyadmin@localhost identified by "redacted";

    Grant USAGE ON mysql.* TO phpmyadmin@localhost;
    GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO phpmyadmin@localhost;
    GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv) ON mysql.tables_priv TO phpmyadmin@localhost;
    GRANT SELECT (Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv) ON mysql.user TO phpmyadmin@localhost;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON phpmyadmin.* TO  phpmyadmin@localhost;
```

I configured `nginx` by adding the following to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` as per https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/install-phpmyadmin-nginx-ubuntu-16-04

```
location /phpmyadmin {
  root /usr/share/;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

  location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  }
 }
```

Navigating to `your-domain.com/phpmyadmin/` and logging in as `phpmyadmin` showed **phpMyAdmin**.
I thought success!, however on navigating to `Databases` I received the following errors:-

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

It seems the earlier attempt had created/modified files in `/etc/phpmyadmin/` which is trying to use the missing password (as per the installation log)

```
Creating config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
dbconfig-common: phpmyadmin configure: trying again.
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
dbconfig-common: phpmyadmin configure: trying again.
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
Replacing config file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf with new version
Replacing config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: How you trying install phpmyadmin - form packages, from sources?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the error you are getting is because some script is trying to execute mysql with no password as root: either you are root or you are using `sudo`:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Assuming your MySQL root user has passwords, you would need to access or interact with MySQL CLI as:
`mysql -u username -p` and password will be requested bellow.

An easy (but not recommended fix) would be to remove the MySQL password for root, perform the whole installation and then re-establish the password. This will allow the installation script to complete fine.

**The right way to fix this** would be to manually locate the `CREATE DATABASE` command at the installation script and run it manually by using the `mysql` command syntax above (using username and password).

## create the configuration storage

1. go to the phpMyAdmin samples: `cd ${installation_path}/phpmyadmin/examples`
2. Import the sample: `# mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql` (this will execute the script that is failing on your installation and will prompt for password)
3. Restart NGINX: `# systemctl restart nginx`

Source http://howtolamp.com/lamp/phpmyadmin/4.2/installing#configuration-storage

Also, the doc for phpmyadmin states specific steps for Debian, which I guess will be similar at Raspbian : https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables